What movie is being used in a fan music video of Jamala's song "1944" about the deportation of Crimean Tatars?
This YouTube video, uploaded last month, (along with a few other uploads) is an unofficial fan video of Jamala's song 1944, a song about the deportation of Crimean Tatars. Some of it is low-quality historical footage, but other parts look like they are from a film. What film is it from?

The film is called Haytarma, a 2013 Crimean Tatar-language film which features the 1944 deportation of the Crimean Tatars, just like the song "1944" does.
This fan video uses clips from the same movie, and has in its description

Видеоролик из фильма "Хайтарма" на песню Джамалы "1944"

which Google translates from Russian into English as

Video from the movie "Haytarma" Jamala for the song "1944"

To discover this fan video, I searched YouTube for Джамала 1944, sorted by upload date, and looked amongst the oldest videos.
